# FOS UserBundle I want to have two login views for frontend and backend. Is it possible?

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to override the layouts of fos user bundle and everything is ok but if I want to have two different login views I cannot find a good solution for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "having different views"? Is it purely CSS stuffs or are you trying to authenticate an user against a different user provider?

Answer (score 2):

I never tried it, but I think you need to override the controller from FOSUserBundle and put the logic to decide what view to render.

More info: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

Comment: Yes, this is the proper way